Draw arrow from data coordinates to AnnotationBBox
I have a figure with two axis, and an annotation box that sits below the top axis. I want an arrow that starts at the data point in the top axis and points to the top-center of the box (currently it points to 0,0, see picture below). How can I do this?

The position of the box is influenced by

the data coordinates (in x dimension)
the axes fraction (in y dimension)
the box is moved by a certain amount of points (using boxcoords and xybox, respectively)
and the box is moved w.r.t. the anchorpoint (using the box_alignment
argument).

Here is the code that generated the figure:
%matplotlib ipympl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnnotationBbox, DrawingArea

# Create figure and axes
fig = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)

ax1.plot(0.3,0.4,'ok')

# Dimensions and position of the annotation box
box_width, box_height = 20, 20
box_position = (0.2, 0)  # Place it in the center of the axes

# Create the box
box = DrawingArea(box_width, box_height)

# Create the AnnotationBbox
annotation_box = AnnotationBbox(box, 
                                box_position, # xy, controlled by xycoords
                                xycoords=('data', 'axes fraction'),
                                xybox = (0,-30), # additional shift, controlled by boxcoords
                                boxcoords="offset points",
                                pad=0.5,
                                box_alignment=(0.5,1),
                                annotation_clip=False)

# Add the annotation box to the desired axis (e.g., ax1)
ax1.add_artist(annotation_box)

# Ensure that this annotation is drawn on top of everything else by adjusting the zorder
annotation_box.set_zorder(10)

arrow = FancyArrowPatch(
    posA=(0.3,0.4), 
    posB=(0,0),  # should be updated to point to the annotation box
    arrowstyle="->",
    mutation_scale=10,
    color="black",
    linewidth=1,
    clip_on = False
)
ax1.add_patch(arrow)

# Show plot
plt.show()

I have head a look at matplotlibs transformation tutorial but I cannot seem to get it right.
The ideal solution would work independent of which coordinate systems are used to place the AnnotationBBox (e.g. if xycoords was changed to something else, it would be ideal if the solution still works)

Am I understanding correctly that you want the arrow to point from the point in the top plot to the top-center of the box in the bottom plot?

Yes, but note that the box is placed w.r.t. the top plot (i.e. the top center is 30 points below the bottom of the top axis, and the x position is 0.2 in data coordinates of the top plot)

Why are you adjusting the box' position both with xybox and box_alignment and adjusting the size both with DrawingArea and pad? - you're making it maximally hard to determine where the actual center of the top is.

In y-direction, the box is supposed to stay at a constant distance below the top axis (30 points). This distance shouldn't change if the figure is resized. In x-direction, the position needs to correspond to a given point in data coordinates. This is all I want to achieve.  My solution so far is setting the box_position to 0 in y and use 'axes fraction' for xzcoords in y. That makes it flush with the bottom of the top axes. To move the box down by 30 points I use boxcoords. To have this point be the top center I use box_alignment.

Pad can be set to 0.

Can you explain why exactly you need a box, positioned relative to the top chart, to sit on top of another chart? I get the sense that you're asking this to solve another, real problem that has a better solution overall - an XY problem.

Essentially the question is: how can I find the coordinate of an AnnotationBBox that is generated in arbitraty ways. Matplotlib must know where that box is, there must be some way to read it out. The 'real world problem': I show aggregated data in the top plot. Depending on where the user clicks in the top plot, an annotation appears below the top plot for the selected x value. Within the box, I show multiple more detailed visualizations of the data. The box can be toggled on and off, so it only is on top of the bottom plot if that particular feature is used, but not in general.

Part of the problem here is that adding the arrow to the plot can change the extent of what needs to be rendered, which changes the coordinates in the figure. You're mixing coordinates of what is in a plot and what is in the figure. If you have a figure that renders correctly, adding an annotation in an unobtrusive way is possible, and you can find out the relative coordinates of everything you need. But what you have has so many undesirable interactions, it's not really possible to give an answer without a clearer example of what chart you want to add something to.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I guess the easiest way is to use display coords:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnnotationBbox, DrawingArea, FancyArrowPatch
from matplotlib.transforms import IdentityTransform
import numpy as np

# Create figure and axes
fig = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)

np.random.seed(42)
ax1.plot(np.random.rand(10)/3, np.random.rand(10), 'o', picker=True)

# Dimensions and position of the annotation box
box_width, box_height = 20, 20
box_position = (0.2, 0)  # Place it in the center of the axes

# Create the box
box = DrawingArea(box_width, box_height)

# Create the AnnotationBbox
annotation_box = AnnotationBbox(box, 
                                box_position, # xy, controlled by xycoords
                                xycoords=('data', 'axes fraction'),
                                xybox = (0,-30), # additional shift, controlled by boxcoords
                                boxcoords="offset points",
                                pad=0.5,
                                box_alignment=(0.5,1),
                                annotation_clip=False)

# Add the annotation box to the desired axis (e.g., ax1)
ax1.add_artist(annotation_box)

# Ensure that this annotation is drawn on top of everything else by adjusting the zorder
annotation_box.set_zorder(10)

def onpick(event):
    tb = annotation_box.get_tightbbox()
    arrow = FancyArrowPatch(
        posA=(ax1.transData.transform((event.mouseevent.xdata, event.mouseevent.ydata))), 
        posB=((tb.x0 + tb.x1) / 2, tb.y1),
        arrowstyle="->",
        mutation_scale=10,
        clip_on=False,
        transform=IdentityTransform(),
    )
    for p in ax1.patches:
        p.remove()
    ax1.add_patch(arrow)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

plt.show()


